# Store 2 bytes from I2C Slave

Tags: c, i2c

struggling with what is probably a straightforward piece of code to copy 2 bytes received from an I2C slave into an array so I can then convert to INT and perform maths on the data.

This code successfully (according to my I2C analyser) reads 2 consecutive bytes from one register address on a 16bit ADC.

```
void ADC_Initialise( void )
{
    _DINT() ;                              // disable all maskable interrupts

    I2C_SCL_HIGH() ;
    I2C_SCL_OUTPUT() ;
    I2C_SDA_HIGH() ;
    I2C_SDA_OUTPUT() ;

    I2C_Write_Register_3B( ADC, 0x01, 0xC0, 0x83) ;  // Write 2 bytes to ADC Config Register

    for(i=0; i < 10000; i++);

    I2C_Read_Register( ADC, 0x00 );      // Read the 2 byte ADC value

    for(i=0; i < 10000; i++);
    _EINT() ;                             // re-enable the interrupts
}

static unsigned char I2C_Read_Register( char Device_Address, char Register_Address )

{
    unsigned char Value ;

    I2CM_Start( ) ;

    if( I2CM_Out( Device_Address << 1 ) )    //send write control byte + chip address
        return 0 ;

    else if( I2CM_Out( Register_Address ) )  //send register number
        return 0 ;

    I2CM_Start( ) ;                          // Restart

    if( I2CM_Out(( Device_Address << 1 ) | 0x01 ))      //send read control byte + chip address
    return 0 ;

    I2CM_In( &Value, 2 ) ;                    //RJ  6.8.19 input 2 byte ADC value to 'buf'

//      return Value ;                          //rj placed after IC2M_In
    I2CM_Stop( ) ;

    return Value ;                              //rj placed after IC2M_Stop
}


static void I2CM_In( unsigned char* buf, int count )
{
    unsigned char data ;

    for( ; count--; )  // How do I store these 2 bytes in a char[] or INT
    {
            data = 0 ;
            I2C_SDA_INPUT() ;

        volatile unsigned int i = 0 ;

        for( ; i < 8 ; ++i )
        {
            //Set Clock High
            I2C_SCL_HIGH() ;              

            //shift the bit over
            data <<= 1 ;

            if( I2C_SDA_IS_HIGH() )
            {
                data |= 0x01 ;
            }
            //Set Clock Low
            brief_pause( 0x04 ) ;
            I2C_SCL_LOW() ;
        }
        //put the input data byte into the buffer, inc buffer pointer
        *buf++ = data ;

        //take sda to output ack
        I2C_SDA_OUTPUT() ;

        //Set Clock High
        I2C_SCL_HIGH() ;

        //Set Clock Low
        brief_pause( 0x04 ) ;
        I2C_SCL_LOW() ;
    }
}
```

So, presumably I then need an array (unsigned char adcarray [2] to collect / store the resulting reads, so I tried -

```
*buf++ = data ;

adcarray[] = data ;

adcarray[] = buf ;
```

'expected an expression' presumably means I need some form of for loop to populate the array on each pass, even though the *buf line is already inside a count 2 loop.

Assistance appreciated (C in IAR on MSP430 and ADS1115 ADC).
Regards, Ralph

Comment: What is `adcarray` or `Value` - you've left out the declarations for those variables.

Comment: Hello Chris, Value is 2 x 8 bit values read consecutively from a 16bit register on the adc. I need to put those in an array or ideally an INT.

Comment: The function already takes a pointer and a length value where the data is to be stored. Why not call that function with the address of your array?

Comment: Please always provide complete information about error messages. What is the exact text and for what line is it reported? The snippet is not part of the function above. Please always provide complete verifyable program to reproduce your problem.

Comment: How do you verify if you successfully read the data? Where do you compare the read values with the I2C analyser?

Comment: Hello Gerhardh - I've added  adcdata[count] = data ; immediately after the *buf++ = data ; but I am not sure it is working properly, the array seems to be empty

Comment: I have a ZeroPlus logic state analyser which shows me the 2 bytes being read correctly, I just need to store them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197600/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-ralph).

Comment: sorry, I will come back to you, I have other major issues with the I2C code

Comment: If array has all zero values then your function I2C_SDA_IS_HIGH() seems to be problem.
If you want to put this data in Integer variable, you would like to look into byte order of network and host. (https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl)

Comment: Hello Sunil, note that there is nothing wrong with the I2C code as my analyser shows the 2 bytes being read in sequence and they contain the expected values. My problem is how do I put those 2 bytes into an array or int so I can perform maths etc (2's compliment number)

Comment: Your code is still rather incomplete. What is `Value`? It should contain the 2 bytes  read by 'I2CM_In`. What's wrong with the content of `Value`? Is it different from what you see in your analyzer?

Comment: Yes, very different, the values shown in the analyser are 3E for the first byte and f) for the second. The value of Value (according to IAR) is 'unknown or ambiguous sysmbol'

Comment: I have now shown 'all the code' but that is likely to just confuse people, the issue is that I still cant figure out how to save the bytes so I can int / scale them etc. I suspect I am missing something simple.

Comment: `unsigned char Value;` How is this supposed to hold 2 bytes?

Comment: I2C_Read_Register( ADC, 0x00 ) returns 2 bytes (according to the I2C analyser), holding them is the problem that I am looking for a solution for.

Comment: I need to add something after this *buf++ = data to store / hold the 2 bytes, but I don't know what (arrays, ints etc dont seem to work)

Comment: Value is a fallback from TI's supposed I2C example code, it is no surprise to me that it doesn't work with more than one byte.

Comment: The problem is that the actual variable behind `buf` *is* `Value`, which only allocates a byte of memory. Value should probably be an array or a 16 bit int, and the function `I2C_Read_Register` should return a 16 bit int. If you shove a breakpoint at `*buf++ = data ;`, do you see the same thing your analyzer sees?

Comment: Thanks but solved, a very simple (albeit messy) if count = 0 or if count = 1 (immediately after  *buf++ = data) then store the associated byte in a separate char.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to store the data in another array with the I2CM_In function, you are using it wrong.

```
static void I2CM_In( unsigned char* buf, int count )
{
    unsigned char data ;

    for( ; count--; )
    {
        ....
        //put the input data byte into the buffer, inc buffer pointer
        *buf++ = data ;
    }
}
```

The data received is already stored in a buffer: `buf`.
It is your job to provide a buffer that is suitable to store the result.

```
static unsigned char I2C_Read_Register( char Device_Address, char Register_Address )
{
    unsigned char Value ;
...
    I2CM_In( &Value, 2 ) ;  // << Value is 1 byte!
...
  return Value ;
}
```

If you want to read a register with 16 bit, you cannot return the value as an `unsigned char`. You must use a data type capable of holding (at least) 2 bytes.

By telling the function that the buffer is 2 bytes long, you also cause undefined behaviour.

```
static uint16_t I2C_Read_Register( char Device_Address, char Register_Address )
{
    uint16_t Value ;
...
    I2CM_In( &Value, 2 ) ;
...
    return Value ;
}
```

Depending on the endianess you might also need to switch byte order:

```
static uint16_t I2C_Read_Register( char Device_Address, char Register_Address )
{
    uint8_t tmp_Value[2] ;
...
    I2CM_In( tmp_Value, 2 ) ;
    uint16_t Value;

#if MSB_FIRST
    Value = ((uint16_t)tmp_Value[0]) << 8 || tmp_Value[1];
#else // LSB_FIRST
    Value = ((uint16_t)tmp_Value[1]) << 8 || tmp_Value[0];
#endif
...
    return Value ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what I actually used (albeit fairly horrible) was -                                              if (count == 0)              {
        ADC_Value2 = data ;
        }
        
        if (count == 1)
        {
        ADC_Value1 = data ;
        }

Comment: Of course then attempting to combine the two separate chars into an int (for maths work) doesn't work (using standard shift first char 8 bits left, add second char etc (in IAR Workbench) but that's another story

Comment: You might try to cast the value to int before shifting.